# Angular 4 - Access files which is in the local machine

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access a file which is available in "**D:\Angular Project\sample.txt**". Need to show this contents in Text Field. How to fetch the contents.

Comment: I hope this is not possible. The security implications would be disastrous.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470453/angular-2-angular-4-how-can-i-access-file-from-the-local-system-location

Comment: your server should be the one doing the reading not your Angular. Because it doesn't have a permission to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your help