# How can I access video file from the local system location using Angular?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular14

I'm trying to access video file using my system path but it's not working. However it's working fine if I put this file inside src\app\assets folder in my application.
My html code are:

```
 <video id="my_video_1" autoplay preload="metadata" loop controls *ngFor="let v of VideoById">
<source src="{{v.videopath}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I have to give in src like this src="D:\Video\video01.mp4", how is it possible

my project path are **"C:\Projects\VideoStreamingApp"** and my video file path are **"D:\Video\video01.mp4"**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 / Angular 4 : How can I access file from the local system location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470453/angular-2-angular-4-how-can-i-access-file-from-the-local-system-location)

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and then just type

```
d:
cd video
```

and then specify a video player, for example

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "D:\Video\video01.mp4"
```

Opening video01.mp4 from directory D:\Video with VLC player.

Comment: I m not using vlc player. I m using angular video player